# It appears Google published a bad cidr block for googleusercontent (35.216.0/15)

Tags: dns

Around 9:30 am ip address parsing from Google User Content TXT records starting failing, because a new block google published doesn't appear to be valid cidr. If you run the code below, you'll notice that it's the only block that doesn't contain 4 octets:

````
cessien:~ cessien$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do dig txt _cloud-netblocks$i.googleusercontent.com | grep -a1 'ANSWER SECTION'; done;

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com. 2176 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks6.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks7.googleusercontent.com ip4:8.34.208.0/20 ip4:8.35.192.0/21 ip4:8.35.200.0/23 ip4:108.59.80.0/20 ip4:108.170.192.0/20 ip4:108.170.208.0/21 ?all"

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com. 2176 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:162.216.148.0/22 ip4:162.222.176.0/21 ip4:173.255.112.0/20 ip4:192.158.28.0/22 ip4:199.192.112.0/22 ip4:199.223.232.0/22 ip4:199.223.236.0/23 ip4:23.236.48.0/20 ip4:23.251.128.0/19 ip4:35.204.0.0/14 ip4:35.208.0.0/13 ?all"

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com. 557 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:107.167.160.0/19 ip4:107.178.192.0/18 ip4:146.148.2.0/23 ip4:146.148.4.0/22 ip4:146.148.8.0/21 ip4:146.148.16.0/20 ip4:146.148.32.0/19 ip4:146.148.64.0/18 ip4:35.203.0.0/17 ip4:35.203.128.0/18 ip4:35.203.192.0/19 ip4:35.203.240.0/20 ?all"

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_cloud-netblocks4.googleusercontent.com. 557 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:130.211.8.0/21 ip4:130.211.16.0/20 ip4:130.211.32.0/19 ip4:130.211.64.0/18 ip4:130.211.128.0/17 ip4:104.154.0.0/15 ip4:104.196.0.0/14 ip4:208.68.108.0/23 ip4:35.184.0.0/14 ip4:35.188.0.0/15 ip4:35.216.0/15 ?all"

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_cloud-netblocks5.googleusercontent.com. 2919 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:35.190.0.0/17 ip4:35.190.128.0/18 ip4:35.190.192.0/19 ip4:35.235.224.0/20 ip4:35.192.0.0/14 ip4:35.196.0.0/15 ip4:35.198.0.0/16 ip4:35.199.0.0/17 ip4:35.199.128.0/18 ip4:35.200.0.0/15 ip4:35.235.216.0/21 ip6:2600:1900::/35 ?all"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is invalid per RFC7208 that says:

> It is not    permitted to omit parts of the IP address instead of
>   using CIDR    notations.  That is, use 192.0.2.0/24 instead of
>   192.0.2.

For example the validator at https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-syntax-validator says:

> Invalid SPF Policy
>
> The policy contains one or more syntax errors.
>
> Invalid IP address notation "35.216.0" for the "ip4" mechanism. Only
>   IPv4 dotted-quad decimal addresses are accepted, e.g. 192.0.2.0.

However technically, the /15 means you need only the first two bytes, as you need only 15 bits, contained in the first 16 bits of the two first bytes.

`35.216.0/15` is everything from `35.216.0.0` to `35.217.255.255`

Comment: Thanks for citing the RFC. I feel like this must've been a (human) mistake, but I'm not sure how to route this